# How to convert fisheye model parameters calibrated in OpenCV into fisheye in Blender?

Tags: python, fisheye

I want to simulate a real-world fisheye in Blender, using parameters calibrated in OpenCV. However, I don't know how to map these parameters into Blender.

[image]

[image]